# Internetless/Remote Arch Install

Tags: arch-linux, osx

Don't have a WiFi card compatible with any modules for Linux or Ethernet, but I do have working OS X install with WiFi. Do have brew on OS X, and it being OSX, most Linux programs will run. How can I install Arch in this scenario?

What are my install options? I have heard If I am running a existing Linux install (not sure if BSD/Darwin counts, hoping it does) I can do a install without booting to **LIVE ARCH LINUX DISK**. Will I have hope? I don't need wifi, I just need it installed with packages!

Comment: Well, you could just get an USB Wi-Fi adapter that is supported by Linux and use this at least temporarily.

Comment: @renan Well, I could, but I don't have it :(

Comment: Could I predownload packages on a USB for Arch to install????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could install a virtual machine manager that can access partitions on the host system during install like VirtualBox.

- Repartition your drive in OS X with Disk Utility so you have space to install Arch Linux.
- Install VirtualBox for OS X. In order to have VirtualBox access a partition you will have to manually edit a vmdk file.
- Install Arch Linux inside VirtualBox on a real partition of the host system. To be on the safe side, make sure you only give access to your new Arch Linux partition and not the OS X or EFI partition at this point.
- Since Arch does not recommend installing GRUB2 to a partition boot sector, and most other bootloaders are not officially supported, I recommend using [syslinux and GUID partition table layout](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_Guide#Syslinux) (GPT) instead of MBR.
- Make sure to edit syslinux.cfg so that the APPEND statement contains your disk UUID instead of the device path. See [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/UUID#by-uuid) how to find partition UUID's.
- Install reFind bootloader in OS X. The next time you boot, it will scan your partitions and find your Arch install and give you the option to boot it.

Comment: Okay, I haven't tried it but that should in theory work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you can of course mount a partition and chroot into it since OSX is UNIX-ish... But Practically, I think it would be a bad idea. You will be running a linux partition with an OSX kernel. The kernel at some point might ruin the day for you. :( The best bet is to find out about your WiFi card and look it up here:

http://wireless.kernel.org/

If you find it, then it is very likely that you will be able to get it to work somehow.

Comment: Found it under: IT WILL NEVER EVEN WORK!

Comment: Sorry to hear so, man. In this case, your best bet is a USB adapter. There are some that are as cheap as $4 or $5. So the price would not be much of an issue.